# SQL Server 2012, Selecting two max records then joining

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, left-join

I'm trying to conduct a multi-table join that uses the common ScheduledObjectID field. I'd like to select multiple records from a table based on the max RunID and UserDueDate. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sample data:

```
ScheduledObjectID RunID   UserDueDate
-------------------------------------------------
123               1       2017-07-16 14:26:56.263
123               2       2017-05-16 14:26:56.250
123               3       2017-05-16 14:26:56.233
456               9       2017-05-16 14:26:56.217
456               10      2017-05-16 14:26:56.200
456               11      2017-10-07 10:19:33.873
```

Desired join data

```
ScheduledObjectID RunID   UserDueDate
-------------------------------------------------
123               3       2017-05-16 14:26:56.233
456               11      2017-10-07 10:19:33.873
```

Comment: Add your current query that creates the sample data above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of join, you can use top 1 with ties

<kbd>[demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/738558/demo)</kbd>

```
select top 1 with ties ScheduledObjectID, RunID,   UserDueDate
from
#tmp 
order by 
row_number() over (Partition by ScheduledObjectID order by runid desc)
```

As per comments  this should work:

```
select * from t1 join
(select ScheduledObjectID,max(runid) as runid,max(userduedate) as userduedate
from t2
```

group by ScheduledObjectID
    ) t2
    on t1.somecol1=t2.somecol

Comment: Sorry, should've explained better. The data above is one of the join tables that is linking to other data via the ScheduledObjectID column.

Comment: Please check the edit,if that is what you are looking for